# Eloquent - How to use "Has Many Through" relation?

Tags: eloquent, has-many-through, laravel-5.6, eloquent-relationship

I have three tables - products, features and product_feature - as

```
products
    - id
    - name
features
    - id
    - key
product_feature
    - product_id
    - feature_id
    - value
```

I was retrieve all (key, value) pairs for a product. The SQL statement is

```
SELECT key, value FROM products
JOIN product_feature pf
ON pf.product_id = "Product ID"
JOIN features f
ON f.id = pf.feature_id
```

How do I established that relationship

```
// Inside Product model
function features() {
    // Has many through relationship
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [`BelongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship:

```php
public function features() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Feature::class, 'product_feature')->withPivot('value');
}

foreach($product->features as $feature) {
    // $feature->key
    // $feature->pivot->value
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to access the value attribute without using pivot?
Like `$feature->value`

Comment: You can replace `->withPivot('value')` with `->select('features.*', 'product_feature.value')`, but that's not recommended.